# NSTableView - Trying to fit exactly 9 rows

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I'm trying to size the rows of a NSTableView to exactly 9 rows fit. I've tried `[menuTableView setRowHeight:floor(menuRect.size.height / 9)];` and I've tried `[menuTableView setRowHeight:(menuRect.size.height / 9)];` and `[menuTableView setRowHeight:ceil(menuRect.size.height / 9)];` but all of them have the same issue, if I've selected row 0 then row 9 is clipped at the bottom and if I select row 9 then row 0 is clipped at the top.

How can I set up a NSTableView to show 9 full rows so no matter what there is never a partial row visible?

Thanks,

*edit*: Yes menuRect is the frame for the menuTableView

*edit*:

Below is the full method I use to position the NSTableView and set the row height I've tried to remove any rounding issues with the use of the `rowHeight` variable. You can see with the attached screen shot that the last row isn't fully displayed

```
- (void) updateGUIPositions
{
    NSRect screenRect = [self frame];
    NSRect menuRect;

    // Set the menu location on screen
    NSInteger spacer =  screenRect.size.width / 9;
    menuRect.size.width = floor(screenRect.size.width - (spacer * 3)) / 2;
    menuRect.size.height = ceil(screenRect.size.height - (spacer * 2));
    NSInteger rowHeight = menuRect.size.height / 9;
    menuRect.size.height = rowHeight * 9;
    menuRect.origin.x = menuRect.size.width + (spacer * 2);
    menuRect.origin.y = spacer;
    [menuScrollView setFrame:menuRect];

    // Setup the row height
    [menuTableView setRowHeight:rowHeight];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work, but it sounds like a rounding error(I had the same problem with a UITableView). Try making the height of the NSTableView's frame 1px larger. So, `menuTableView.frame.height = menuTableView.frame.height+1;`

EDIT
Try using this...

```
`float rowHeight = menuRect.size.height / 9.0f;`
```

Comment: using floats produces the same output as well :-/

Comment: You should use `CGFloat`, not `float`.  In the 64 bit environment, it is a `double`.  Not that that is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fix the size of the rows and instead set the size of the frame programmatically, this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376518/fixed-height-nstableview-avoid-scrolling) suggests this formula works:

```
numRows * (rowHeight + intercellSpacing.height)
```

Using that formula, the scroller will draw, but you could just turn it off.